# Adjusting sampling points to closest land surface QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, point

I have many sampling points in mangroves of Southeast Asia and am trying to extract climatic data for each using the WorldClim dataset. However, many of the points fall on areas classified as "water" for which the WorldClim dataset values do not exist.

How do I adjust each of the point long/lat values to the closest land value in QGIS? Alternatively, if there's a way of doing so in Program R, I'd also be interested in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is easier to turn the solution around and expand the worldclim data a bit, via a focal operation that only fills in NA values. In R you can do that like this

```
 r <- focal(x, w=matrix(1,nrow=5,ncol=5), fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE, NAonly=TRUE)
 z <- extract(xy, r)
```

where `x` is the worldclim data and xy your `c(lon, lat)` points.

Comment: Interesting proposal. It helps, but there are still NAs when I extract the points. Would I just need to expand the matrix size to compensate for that? Is it possible to visualize the new raster in QGIS following the adjustment?

Comment: add `filename = "abc.tif"` to see it in qgis. Yes, you could make a larger matrix (but at some point the location is probably wrong, not just a bit off) or, perhaps better, run the same function twice.

Comment: okay, cool. thank you! as another alternative for someone who might be looking, my friend also pointed out this java program for the same task: http://www.phycoweb.net/software/rasterGIS/index.html